# bonobo git server aspxerrorpath

Tags: asp.net, git, bonobo

I have a problem with a bonobo git server.
Everything was working fine until I created a new folder in the "repositories" folder used to store all the git repos.
Now when I try to access the web interface I get:

> http://host/server.git/Home/Error?aspxerrorpath=/server.git

I deleted the sub folder created in "repositories".
I checked again all the settings of the bonobo server as indicated here "https://bonobogitserver.com/install/"

Is there any way to get the server working again without reinstalling the bonobo git server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad :P.
But maybe this will help others.

In the "App_Data\Logs" folder I checked the last log and found a lot of this :P :

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'X:\git\repositories' is denied.

I then proceeded to give read/write access to the Users of the station. And everything resumed working.